# rails callback before_create broken after_validate works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, activemodel, rails-models

I have a `Printer` model to which I added a `master` boolean column. A printer `belongs_to :restaurant`. The `master` flag indicated whether this printer is the primary printer of this restaurant.

I have a method in the Printer model:

```
def set_master_on_create
  if self.restaurant.printers.empty?
    self[:master] = true
  else
    self[:master] = false
  end
end
```

and set this callback: `before_create :set_master_on_create`

If I run this method as a `before_create` then creating a new printer will fail. If I change the callback to `after_validation` creating the new object will work flawlessly, even with the `:on => :create` option.

Does Rails freeze the object so i can no longer change values after a certain point which will cause the `Rollback` I get? Any help appreciated.

I am on Rails 3.2.2 and sqlite in dev mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is that a before_create method returning false will prevent your object from being saved. try adding a `return true`

and i guess you set the master attribute like this: `self.master = true`

```
def set_master_on_create
  if self.restaurant.printers.empty?
    self.master = true
  else
    self.master = false
  end

  return true
end
```

> If a before_* callback cancels the action a ROLLBACK is issued. You
>   can also trigger a ROLLBACK raising an exception in any of the
>   callbacks, including after_* hooks. Note, however, that in that case
>   the client needs to be aware of it because an ordinary save will raise
>   such exception instead of quietly returning false.
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html